# What's the equivalent of Clojure's iterate function in Racket

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, racket

I'm playing with Racket today, and trying to produce an indefinite sequence of numbers based on multiple applications of the same function.

In Clojure I'd use the *iterate* function for this, but I'm not sure what would be the equivalent in Racket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most situations you can replace the use of `iterate` with `for/fold`.

```
> (define (mult2 x) (* x 2))

> (for/fold ([x 1])   ; the initial value of x is 1
            ([i 8])   ; count i=0,...,7
   (mult2 x))         ; put x = (mult2 x)
256
```

The advantage of `for/fold` is that you can iterate more variables at a time:

```
(define (mult2 x) (* x 2))
(define (div2 x)  (/ x 2))

(for/fold ([x 1]        ; bind x to 1
           [y 1])       ; bind y to 1
          ([i 8])       ; i=0,...,7
  (values (mult2 x)     ; put x = (mult2 x)
          (div2  y)))   ; put y = (div2 y)
```

This will return two values: `256` and `1/256`.

Collecting elements are easy. Here is the Fibonacci example:

```
(for/fold ([fs '(1)]     ; list of fibonacci numbers generated so far
           [f1   1]      ; a fibonacci number
           [f2   1])     ; the following fibonacci number
          ([i   10])     ; i = 0,...,9
  (values (cons f2 fs)   ; cons the new fibonacci number to the list fs
          f2             ; put f1 = (the old) f2
          (+ f1 f2)))    ; put f2 = (the old) f1+f2
```

The result consists of three values:

```
'(89 55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1)
89
144
```

Comment: Also - expect `for/fold` to be more faster than stream.

Comment: Well, of course eager comprehensions are much more lightweight than streams. ;-) I should actually write an `in-iterate` sequence generator that can be used directly with `for` comprehensions.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young That is a nice idea.

Comment: I've posted my `in-iterate` as a new answer. What I like about it is that it handles multiple values without making the user do funky argument packing and unpacking (unlike Óscar's answer and my initial answer). Actually, I'd like to see that become part of Racket's standard library someday...(my code is released under "public-domain-style" CC0, use freely with or without attribution).

Answer (score 6):

[SRFI 41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html) (`(require srfi/41)`) provides `stream-iterate` directly.

You can use Óscar's examples and substitute `stream-iterate` wherever you see `iterate`, without having to define your own `iterate`. In addition, you can simulate Clojure's parameter destructuring using `match-lambda`:

```
(require srfi/41)
(define fib
  (stream-map first
              (stream-iterate (match-lambda
                                ((list a b)
                                 (list b (+ a b))))
                              '(0 1))))
(stream->list 10 fib)  ; => (0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no direct equivalent within the built-in Racket procedures, but we can implement something with a similar functionality using [streams](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html). Try this:

```
(define (stream-take m s)
  (if (zero? m)
      '()
      (cons (stream-first s)
            (stream-take (sub1 m) (stream-rest s)))))

(define (iterate f x)
  (stream-cons x (iterate f (f x))))
```

For instance, here's how the examples from the Clojure [documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate) would look like in Racket:

```
(stream-take 5 (iterate add1 5))
=> '(5 6 7 8 9)

(stream-take 10 (iterate (curry + 2) 0))
=> '(0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18)

(define powers-of-two (iterate (curry * 2) 1))
(stream-ref powers-of-two 10)
=> 1024
(stream-take 10 powers-of-two)
=> '(1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512)

(define fib
  (stream-map first
              (iterate (lambda (pair)
                         (list (second pair)
                               (+ (first pair) (second pair))))
                       '(0 1))))
(stream-take 10 fib)
=> '(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on soegaard's idea to use eager comprehensions, here's an `in-nest-sequence` sequence generator (also available [on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/106806/216) and [as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/cky/e5efa325fa497b45c9cd)):

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax unstable/syntax))
(provide (rename-out [*in-nest-sequence in-nest-sequence]))

(define in-nest-sequence
  (case-lambda
    [(func init)
     (make-do-sequence
      (thunk (values identity func init #f #f #f)))]
    [(func . inits)
     (make-do-sequence
      (thunk (values (curry apply values)
                     (lambda (args)
                       (call-with-values (thunk (apply func args)) list))
                     inits #f #f #f)))]))

(define-sequence-syntax *in-nest-sequence
  (lambda () #'in-nest-sequence)
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [[(x ...) (_ func init ...)]
       (unless (= (syntax-length #'(x ...)) (syntax-length #'(init ...)))
         (raise-syntax-error 'in-nest-sequence
                             (format "~a values required" (syntax-length #'(x ...)))
                             stx #'(init ...)))
       (with-syntax ([for-arity (syntax-length #'(init ...))]
                     [(value ...) (generate-temporaries #'(init ...))]
                     [(y ...) (generate-temporaries #'(init ...))])
         #'[(x ...) (:do-in ([(f) func])
                            (unless (procedure-arity-includes? f for-arity)
                              (raise-arity-error f (procedure-arity f) init ...))
                            ([value init] ...)
                            #t
                            ([(x ...) (values value ...)]
                             [(y ...) (f value ...)])
                            #t
                            #t
                            (y ...))])])))
```

Sequences generated by `in-nest-sequence` do not terminate, so you will want to pair it with either a sequence that does, or a `#:break` or similar termination condition. For example (using the `powers-of-two` example in Óscar's answer):

```
;; first ten powers of 2
(for/list ((_ (in-range 10))
           (x (in-nest-sequence (curry * 2) 1)))
  x)
; => (1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512)

;; powers of 2 above 10,000 and below 1,000,000
(for/list ((x (in-nest-sequence (curry * 2) 1))
           #:when (> x 10000)
           #:break (> x 1000000))
  x)
; => (16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288)

;; first power of 2 above 10,000,000
(for/first ((x (in-nest-sequence (curry * 2) 1))
            #:when (> x 10000000))
  x)
; => 16777216
```

And here's the Fibonacci sequence example:

```
;; first ten Fibonacci numbers
(for/list ((_ (in-range 10))
           ((x y) (in-nest-sequence (lambda (a b) (values b (+ a b))) 0 1)))
  x)
; => (0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)

;; first Fibonacci number above 10,000,000
(for/first (((x y) (in-nest-sequence (lambda (a b) (values b (+ a b))) 0 1))
            #:when (> x 10000000))
  x)
; => 14930352
```

Comment: Can't wait to see the `define-sequence-syntax` version too :-)

Comment: That looks great, though I'm going to take a bit of time to digest it. I'm very much a Racket n00b.

Comment: @interstar There's no really easy way to digest `in-*` implementations; they're written using a special domain-specific language (whether that's `make-do-sequence` as I used, or `define-sequence-syntax` as soegaard suggested). But if you like to learn something new, it'll definitely serve that purpose!

Comment: As for the _usage_ of  `in-iterate`, that's easier. For the one-argument case (the `(curry * 2)` example above, which by the way is the same as `(lambda (x) (* 2 x))`), that should be pretty straightforward. The two-argument case just extends the concept (and the function you pass in) to use two arguments, and two return values.

Comment: @soegaard I wrote a first cut of a `define-sequence-syntax` version. I'm a total noob at this, though, so I welcome any critique you have! (Actually, I should post this to Code Review Stack Exchange and see what feedback I get. :-P)